# Accessing contents on the underlying mount point path

Tags: linux, mount

If I have partition `/dev/sda1` which is mounted on root `/`, and I have partition `/dev/sdb1` which is mounted on `/var`, is there a way I can access original contents of `/var` on `sda1` without first unmounting `sdb1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Linux, you can use a bind mount to remount part of the file hierarchy
somewhere else.  So, for example, you could do:

```
# mkdir /mnt/bindroot
# mount --bind / /mnt/bindroot
```

At that point, `/mnt/bindroot` contain the contents of the root filesystem,
but without other filesystems mounted on the various directories.

```
# ls /home
user1 lost+found

# ls /mnt/bindroot/home
<whatever was in /home before a filesystem was mounted over it>
```

For FreeBSD, you can do something similar with `nullfs` mounts -- see `mount_nullfs`.

Comment: right, "At that point" but after mount somewhere over / --bind can get cancelled, then just run it again ;-)

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you can do that without a bind-mount and root privileges, by just having a process which either chdir's to or opens the underlying directory --before being hidden by the mount-- and then just lingers on; other processes could then access the directory via `/proc/<pid>/cwd` or `/proc/<pid>/fd/<dir_fd>`.

Example with chdir:

```
# mkdir dir; touch dir/file                   # create a sample dir and file
# (cd dir; while sleep 3600; do :; done) &    # start a bg process with its pwd being dir
[1] 3734
# mount -t tmpfs tmpfs dir                    # mount a tmpfs over dir which will hide its previous content
# ls dir
# ls /proc/3734/cwd                           # you can still access the old dir via /proc/<pid>/cwd 
file
```

Example with opening the directory:

```
# mkdir -p dir1; touch dir1/file
# exec 9<dir1
# mount -t tmpfs tmpfs dir1
# ls dir1
# ls /proc/self/fd/9
file
```

---

If you want to do that after the fact, with a directory which was already mounted over, you can create a private namespace and unmount that directory  inside the namespace.

In this case, you can also access it from outside via `/proc/<pid>/root/<path_to_dir>`, without having to open it or chdir to it:

```
mkdir -p dir; touch dir/file
mount -t tmpfs tmpfs dir

unshare -m sh -c 'umount dir; while sleep 1000; do :; done' &
sleep .1
ls "/proc/$!/root/$PWD/dir"  # will show 'file'
```

You can read more about the extra magic of `/proc/<pid>/root` in the `proc(5)` manpage. Notice that you can keep the namespace of a process alive even after the process terminates by bind-mounting its `/proc/<pid>/ns/mnt` somewhere else; you can then re-enter it with `nsenter(1)`.

Comment: In the context of the question, this would involve time travel, wouldn’t it?

Comment: If that means that my answer is worthless and I should remove it: no way. It may help people coming from searches, which may try that mount-bind trick to access a directory which was already a mount point before being mounted over. Being aware of other options may help.

Answer (score 0):

Note: for those who may miss a comment.

`sudo mount --bind original_location backup_link` works, locations under `oldlocation` can be accessed after something is mounted over them and shadows.

But

1. `sudo mount --bind` as I've found out need to be run **after** `mount something original_location`, not beforehand.
2. As it is after shadowing mount, directory higher than one shadowed need to be mounted: `sudo mount --bind parent_of_original_location backup_link`

Comment: Discussed at length [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/672128/moving-var-onto-different-disk-partition/672133#672133)