# How can the original /home directory be accessed from the root directory when the /home directory is transferred to a new volume?

Tags: mount, directory, home

I created a separate partition for the `/home` files and copied the existing files to the new partition but I did not delete the original directory.

When I restart the system the `/` directory does not show the original `/home` but after remounting the original partition in a new directory ie `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1` I can see them again, ie at `/mnt/sda1/home`

Is if it is possible to see the old `/home` in the `/` directory without having to remount them in a new directory?

I can imagine the situation where a user notices that the root directory is using more space than the file listing suggests, or would like to access the old directory.

Comment: Your description is unclear. If you want to see the old /home under the root directory, you have to mount it there. Why is that impossible?

Comment: Your question is similar to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/402051/325065). You can bind mount `/` (or `/home` before it's mounted over) somewhere else if it feels "lighter" to you (though technically is no different from mounting `/dev/sda1` again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options, and I already done them:

1. mount the old disk on some better place (having `sda1` is not the best name: give the disk a name, not the actual location, which may change). Then just symlink the new place of home to the real place: `ln -s /var/disks/disk_root_2017 /home` and so you can access again /home using the alternate location. Note: this method cannot be used for all standard paths (systems may use `../` and `..` has a different meaning across mounting points, compared bash syntax.
2. just mount your disk as `/home` and eventually move all content in a new location (e.g. old_root). Then move the content of the old home: `mv /home/home/* /home/`

Usually one of the two methods is good. And you may want to use a mix of the two, e.g. old `home` with one method and maybe old `/usr/local` or `/pub` or `/var/lib/mysql` with the other method.

Answer (score 0):

You mount your new partition `/home` over the directory `/home`. Therefore, all you see is the new partition. When you unmount the `/home` partition, the old tree becomes visible again.

If you want to see the old `/home` directory tree when the new `/home` partition is mounted, you will have to move it somewhere, e.g.

```
umount /home
mv /home /home.old
mkdir /home
mount /home
```

Now, you can access the old home via `/home.old` and the new `/home` is mounted in its correct location.