# Moving /var onto different disk/partition

Tags: synchronization, move, var

I moved the `/var` directory to a new disk/partition, this part worked well, but I forgot to delete/move the old `/var` path and it is still using space on `/` (root) partition. How could I delete the old `/var` without redo all the process? Any ideas?

This is what I did so far:

```
fdisk -l
mount /dev/sdb /mnt/newvar/
df -h /mnt/newvar/
rsync -aqxP /var/* /mnt/newvar/
umount /mnt/newvar/  /mnt/var/
umount /mnt/newvar/
umount /disk2/
umount /mnt/newvar/
ls -la /mnt/newvar/
df -h
vim /etc/fstab
```

fstab content:

```
UUID=c7c73822-b6e8-4aa4-a4b2-41a70c29568f /boot ext2 defaults 0 2
/dev/mapper/zabbix--vg-swap_1 none swap sw 0 0
/dev/fd0 /media/floppy0 auto rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
UUID="3195ad53-3aaa-418c-bdc0-d341e33d76d3" /var ext3 defaults 0 2
```

Result of the above command:

```
df -P / /var

Filesystem                  1024-blocks     Used Available Capacity Mounted on
/dev/mapper/zabbix--vg-root    11758232 10103908   1033988      91% /
/dev/sdb                       25671996  8720916  15640360      36% /var
```

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Have you ever deleted a directory before? Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/672128/edit) to show what you have tried that isn't working for you in this case.

Comment: Check the old /var isn't mounted, but the new one is.

Comment: Can you show us the layout, a bit better? are you mounting the the partition at the `/var` mountpoint?

Comment: -1 for providing very little information, please [EDIT](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/672128/edit) and push more info in

Comment: Adding to the comment by @LinuxSecurityFreak, the output of `df -P / /var` would confirm that you have `/var` on a different partition.

Comment: @JimL., they have filesystem A, containing the root filesystem, and including `/var`. Then they make filesystem B, containing only the contents of `/var`, and mount that on `/var`. Now the contents of `/var` on filesystem A are not visible, since fs B is mounted on top of that. Deleting `/var` would remove the contents of B, probably causing some trouble, but would leave the now useless "invisible" stuff in place. So no, you can't look at that as just deleting a directory.

Comment: The intent was to get the user to add more detail about the steps taken so far, and the actual point of trouble.  With respect, @ilkkachu, your conjecture may be accurate, but it is conjecture none the less.

Comment: You actually have a `/dev/fd0` on your system? Haven't seen an automounted floppy drive in a while.

Comment: This is a sequencing confusion. During system startup, `/var` is created and used _before_ `/dev/sdb` is available. Moving `/var` doesn't seem like the best choice. Read `man hier` or  https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html

Comment: @waltinator Having the operating system spread out over several disks has been around forever. All of the `/dev/sd?` devices become available to initrd at the same time.

Comment: If the answer below was useful, please consider accepting it so that it will show up in future searches.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a bind mount to access the original device. This does assume that the new /var is on a different partition.

```
mountpoint /var   # confirm that /var is mounted on a different partition. If not, STOP NOW
mkdir /mnt/root
mount --bind / /mnt/root
ls -lid /var /mnt/root/var    # these will be different inodes
ls /var /mnt/root/var   # different file contents if you've updated /var
rm -rf /mnt/root/var
mkdir /mnt/root/var
umount /mnt/root
rmdir /mnt/root
```

As usually suggested, back everything up before trying this
Just as a suggestion to your new configuration. You did not do anything wrong but I would not have done it your way.

First suggestion: you should probably have made a partition in /dev/sdb and created your file system in /dev/sdb1. Maybe pedantic but I don't like using the disk volumes for file systems. Have had problems with this in the past.

Second: you could have created a PV volume on /dev/sdb1 and added that to /dev/mapper/zabbix to extend the volume. This would have put the entire LVM partition on two disks which will increase the probability of data loss if a disk dies but you would not have needed to move any data. However, if a disk dies in your setup you're probably hosed anyway so that is what backups are for.