# missing disk space on server

Tags: linux, centos, disk-usage, xfs

I have a weird problem on one of our servers. Almost half of my disk space is missing.

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3       271G  122G  149G  46% /
devtmpfs        3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.8G  8.0K  3.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.8G  8.6M  3.8G   1% /run
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       497M  120M  378M  24% /boot
tmpfs           778M     0  778M   0% /run/user/600
```

On the other hand, du shows only 6GB used:

```
du -hs /
6.0G    /
```

This is a server where logs often fill the disk up to 100%, so my first response was to restart rsyslog daemon, but that had no effect. I also tried to reboot the server, so it can't be some files that are deleted but still in use from some process. I looked at https://serverfault.com/questions/299839/linux-disk-space-missing where someone suggested to do a `fsck` on reboot but that didn't help. On the same page, someone suggested to look for files on additional mount points, but there are none. I am looking for more suggestions.

The output of `fdisk`:

```
fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 299.5 GB, 299506860032 bytes, 584974336 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 65536 bytes / 65536 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000f1d8a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         1026048    17018879     7996416   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3        17018880   584974335   283977728   83  Linux
```

`lsblk` output:

```
lsblk -f /dev/sda
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                      
├─sda1 xfs          78e8f824-1a2a-4c60-ab7b-6126a192932d /boot
├─sda2 swap         bdbe969d-c59d-4956-ae69-71e2825f93dc [SWAP]
└─sda3 xfs          a9c9da10-5e99-4a14-a207-490e3f676617 /
```

```
`xfs_quota -x -c 'free -h -b'` output:
Filesystem     Size   Used  Avail Use% Pathname
/dev/sda3    270.7G 127.1G 143.5G  47% /
/dev/sda1    496.5M 119.0M 377.5M  24% /boot
Filesystem     Size   Used  Avail Use% Pathname
/dev/sda3    270.7G 127.1G 143.5G  47% /
/dev/sda1    496.5M 119.0M 377.5M  24% /boot
```

`xfs_quota -x -c 'quota -h'` doesn't return anything.
Nobody set any quotas.
It's one server out of several hundred with the same configuration and partition layout deployed at our branch offices, but only this has this problem. Because of some specific reasons, it's the only one that gets its disk filled regularly to 100%. We delete some logs manually every one or two weeks.

Comment: Is that a SSD drive? Probably will not help, but I would try fstrim.

Comment: It's a RAID 1 array on HDDs.

Comment: The result from `fdisk` makes little sense. For example, `sda1` does not use 512000 blocks of 512 bytes each; looking at the start and end block address it uses 1024000 blocks

Comment: It's CentOS 7. I tagged both to get more audience, because there is no noticeable difference between the two. At least not on the part of filesystems support and management.

Comment: You did run `du -hs /` as root didn't you...?

Comment: Have you tried using ncdu?

Comment: @roaima he claims below he did du as root

Comment: @user1403360 Did you  check umounted filesystem with xfs_repair -n /dev/sda3 manually? What it says?

Comment: @user1403360 What xfs_info / outputs?

Answer (score 3):

It seems likely there are a significant number of files hidden under one of the `boot`, `dev`, `run`, `sys` mountpoint directories that are usually inaccessible due to other filesystems being mounted there. Try this to access them from your running system:

```
mkdir /mnt/root
mount --bind / /mnt/root
du -hs /mnt/root/
```

If the `du` returns significantly more that your reported 6 GB used then this is almost certainly the issue. Use this to identify where the missing files are hiding:

```
du -hs /mnt/root/{boot,dev,run,sys}
```

Remember that `/mnt/root` really is your root `/` filesystem, so treat deletions or other file manipulations with great care. In any case do not try to delete any directories directly under `/mnt/root` that might be used as mountpoints.

Comment: Possibly [related](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/672128/moving-var-onto-different-disk-partition/672133#672133)

Comment: I tried this and i didn't find anything.

Comment: i didn't play with partitions, so its highly unlikely that i have something hidden under a mount point. Server stayed the same since installation. Actually it's 1 server out of several 100 with the same configuration and partition layout. But only this has this problem.

Comment: @user1403360 you haven't answered my question from earlier. Did you run `du -hs /` as root?

Comment: @user1403360 I can't help you if you don't answer the questions seeking clarification. Did you try `du -hs /` as root? If not, that can also explain why it can't see all your files

Answer (score 1):

The best tool to figure out what's taking space on a fs (but NOT deleted-but-sill-open-files) is `ncdu`. Try `ncdu -qx /` to diagnose your rootfs.

Since your problem persists after a reboot, it seems that you are not a victim of deleted-but-sill-open-files.

Comment: ncdu didn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

On running system you should check disk usage as root user to have access to all files and dirs.

Maybe your root fs has quota enabled.
Check `xfs_quota -x -c 'free -hi' /`

Boot from live cd (gparted, systemrescue) and `mount /dev/sda3 /mnt` and check `du -csh /mnt/*`  and `df -H`.

Then unmount /dev/sda3 and check   unmounted xfs filesystem on /dev/sda3  with `xfs_repair -n /dev/sda3`.

Read https://mankier.com/8/xfs_repair to know what checks it performs.

Comment: xfs_quota -x -c 'free -hi' /
Filesystem   Inodes   Used   Free Use% Pathname
/dev/sda3    284.0m  78.4k 283.9m   0% /

Comment: And yes, i did run everything as root. I also rebooted with forcefsck and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

> It's 1 server out of several 100 with the same configuration and partition

Can you estmate what real fs usage should be? Is it 6GB is to small?

`df` get info with `statvfs()` wich reports number of free blocks from superblock so 'usage' is calculated value.

By default `du` also counts blocks used by each file and dir it founds.

Because du < df filesystem have

- blocks not counted by fs as free and wich `du` can't account via directory entries or
- directory entries `du` can't access for some reason. Here check permissions, ACLs, SELinux, AppArmor, long filenames  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/619878/153329

Take into account next:

> Also because of some specific it's the only one that gets it's disk filled regularly to 100%. We delete some logs manually every one or two weeks.

If you delete opened file, directory entry with filename is gone but inode is there and kernel delete inode and freeup blocks later when filehandle is closed.

Computer with big uptime may have large number of orphaned inodes, so reboot should help.

> fsck on reboot and it didn't help.

For some reasonse such orphaned inodes may not be deleted by kernel from a bug, power outage, previous directory corruptions so reboot didnt help.

I recommend check umounted filesystem with `xfs_repair /dev/sda3` manually one last time.

If it doesnt help maybe filesystem is corrupted in a way xfs_repair cant correctly update freemap.

Mostly you should trust `du`.

Also check next.

Compare `du -h` with `du -bh /`.

Find sparse files:

```
find / -type f -printf "%S\t%p\n" | gawk '$1 < 1.0 {print}'
```

Maybe there is a huge number of small files with size less then fs block size.

```
xfs_info / | grep bsize
find / -type f -size -4096c | wc -l00
```

Comment: Here `du` usually says it if there's a directory (tree) it can access because of permissions, if the OP's does the same, he should have noticed that. So I don't think that's a likely reason. If `du` can access a directory because something else is mounted over it, there's no way for `du` to even know there's something there, and as a consequence it can't say anything.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity OP already says about that https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/714798/missing-disk-space-on-server/717443?noredirect=1#comment1359162_716821