# Why `mount --bind ` allows to access shadowed mount point if run after shadowing, but not before?

Tags: linux, mount, bind-mount

I've tried to follow the answer to [Accessing contents on the underlying mount point path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402051/accessing-contents-on-the-underlying-mount-point-path/679766#679766) some time ago, it did not work. But recently I've found out it works if `mount --bind` is executed **after** shadowing.

`man mount`:

> The bind mount call attaches only (part of) a  single  filesystem,
> not possible  submounts.

I guess it is this feature that allows to access shadowed mount point. But why it works only if `mount --bind` executed **after**?

Seeing new:

```
$ mkdir -p 1/1 2
$ touch 1/1/text
$ sudo mount --bind 1 2
$ ls 2/1
text
$ sudo mount -t tmpfs tmpfs 1/1
$ ls 2/1
$
```

Seeing old:

```
$ sudo umount 1/1
$ sudo umount 2
$ sudo mount -t tmpfs tmpfs 1/1
$ sudo mount --bind 1 2
$ ls 2/1
text
```

Comment: "The bind mount call attaches only (part of) a single filesystem, not possible submounts."  ... Read that with the implied "*at the time of mounting*"